# How do I react to keypress in a neovim python remote plugin?

Tags: neovim, plugin-system

I'm in neovim command mode and press `x` on keyboard.

What is the best way a python remote plugin can react to this keypress?

What to do if the plugin should react to several different keys?

Here is my setup: Neovim is started like this:

```
NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/nvim nvim
```

`remoteplugin.py` is:

```python
from neovim import attach
nvim = attach('socket', path='/tmp/nvim')
def mycallback():
    //react on 'x' keypress
```

I frankly didn't understand the suggestion on the [neowiki pages](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Plugin-UI-architecture)

```
while true
    handle(next_vim_event())
```

What would be the corresponding python code?

Comment: Did you read through [this](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/remote_plugin.txt#L7)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just define key maps that calls rpc methods.  A fairly complete use of the Python API can be seen in [deoplete.nvim](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim).  You could also inspect the Python client's source code as well: https://github.com/neovim/python-client

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did solve the problem with Tommy A's tip. Non-perfect code is here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8423/start-and-attach-to-neovim-in-same-python-file