# Start and attach to neovim in same python file

Tags: neovim, vimscript-python

I have a working prototype for some kind of linux-based neovim-app. Sole functionality is "vsplit if 'k' is pressed". It is based on tarruda's [`nvim-terminal-edit-py`](https://gist.github.com/tarruda/37f7a3e22996addf8921).

It is started through `start_nvim.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS='/tmp/nvim' /usr/bin/nvim &
./myapp.py
```

`myapp.py` is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, time, subprocess
from neovim import attach

tf = '/tmp/nvim'

env = dict(os.environ)
env['NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS'] = tf

#os.execvpe("nvim", ["nvim"], env)
#subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/nvim"], env=env)
#subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/nvim', '&'], env=env)

nvim = attach("socket", path=tf)

def key_subscribe(key, to):
    cid = nvim.channel_id                                                                                                               
    nvim.command( ('nnoremap <silent> <buffer> %s ' + ':call rpcnotify(%d, "keypress", "%s")<cr>') % (key, cid, to))


def _request_cb(*args):
    pass


def _notification_cb(*args):
    nvim.command('vsplit')


def _setup_cb():
    key_subscribe('k', 'up')


nvim.run_loop(_request_cb, _notification_cb, _setup_cb)
```

How to start `/usr/bin/nvim` from within `myapp.py`, so that `start_nvim.sh` is not necessary?

I did try various things.

Uncommenting the respective line in `myapp.py` and directly executing `./myapp.py`:

`execvpe` does start nvim, but if I press `k` no vsplit is triggered.

`Popen` and `call` yield

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myapp.py", line 18, in <module>
    nvim = attach("socket", path=tf)
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Obviously, Popen/call didn't pass `/tmp/nvim` to `nvim`.

Comment: Did you tried a mapping like `:nmap k :sp<CR>`?

Comment: I actually did something very similar [here](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/blob/master/v.py). I ran into lots of problems that took me a while to figure out, including this exact one. Feel free to look through that for inspiration, how to get around some common problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're starting a Neovim subprocess and it's blocking before processing the rest of your script.  When you quit Neovim, the rest of the script executes well after the file socket has outlived its use to Neovim.

You will need to start it from a thread so that the rest of the script can execute.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import time
import threading
import subprocess

from neovim import attach

tf = '/tmp/nvim'


def start_neovim():
    env = dict(os.environ)
    env['NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS'] = tf
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/nvim'], env=env)


t = threading.Thread(target=start_neovim)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

# Give Neovim time to start
time.sleep(1)

nvim = attach("socket", path=tf)


def key_subscribe(key, to):
    cid = nvim.channel_id
    nvim.command(('nnoremap <silent> <buffer> %s ' + ':call rpcnotify(%d, "keypress", "%s")<cr>') % (key, cid, to))


def _request_cb(*args):
    pass


def _notification_cb(*args):
    nvim.command('vsplit')


def _setup_cb():
    key_subscribe('k', 'up')


nvim.run_loop(_request_cb, _notification_cb, _setup_cb)
```

I hope you're just doing this as an exercise.  Configuring key bindings using the RPC interface is a little silly considering you still have to use Vim's language to do it.

The more common approach is to use `.vim` scripts to setup the keybindings and API, then use Python for things that aren't practical to do in Vim such as networking or long running asynchronous work.

Comment: I need to open several files at the same time, e.g. <F1> opens all the text files concerning class 5, <F2> opens all those belonging to class 6... I need to map and unmap keys several times. The appriopriate modell would be a finite state machine which would be kind of hard in `.vim`-file, I suppose. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Markus Glad I could help.  But, why not post a question regarding what you just explained?